# How to say that someone has too much emotion, more than their position allows?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

I think I've read something in the structure of "he is [adj] [prep] humanly temper", but I can't remember the exact words for someone who should be just but instead let the temper got the better of them. Kind of like Greek gods who get carried away by little things just like a real life human being. Is there really some phrase like this?

Comment: The nearest I can think of is something like [*He is **of a humane temperament.***](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22of+a+humane+temperament%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) But as it stands I think this question is simply too vague to be useful.

Comment: Someone who does not get upset easily is described as 'even-tempered'. Not sure if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: Can you put just a little more context in this question?  There are a number of ways this can be expressed, so we need a little more info to give you the answer you want without having to make big guesses.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan I edited the question!

Comment: @FumbleFingers Question edited. Does "he's subject to human emotions" make sense & say what I really want to say?

Comment: It's not clear to me exactly what you *intend* to say. Are you only interested in pointing out that someone is inclined to get *angry*, and allow this to cloud their judgement? What about if the person is also inclined to fall in love with the wrong person, inappropriately find something funny, etc.?

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'm not exactly looking for a phrase for a specific occasion, but rather a general one describing someone who shows more emotion than their position/status demands. To make things less confusing I should probably delete all the stuff about "anger" from the question description, because I am intended to use this phrase to describe an angry man, but I don't want a phrase that's explicitly associated to anger.

Comment: Well, my understanding is *everybody* normally makes decisions and judgments on the basis of emotions (then we use logic/morality *afterwards*, to justify ourselves). So we're more likely to need terms like @MrTheWalrus's "even-tempered" to describe the less common case of someone who *doesn't* allow emotions to "cloud/influence his judgment". If someone is *excessively* prone to being influenced by their emotions, perhaps *capricious, mercurial* might do, but most such words refer to *unpredictable* behaviour rather than specifically "emotion-based" reactions.

Comment: "Emotionally immature"?  "Slave to his emotions"?

Comment: Maybe something like this? *He's {subjected to/affected by/corrupted by} human temper.*

Answer (score 1):

My humble suggestion is

> He lets emotions [get the better of](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/get_the_better_of#English) him.

Or maybe

> He fails to [walk the line](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/walk_the_line).

One of the definitions for "walk the line", per Wiktionary, is

> (idiomatic) To behave in an authorized or socially accepted manner, especially as prescribed by law or morality; to exercise self-control.

"Walk the line" and "[toe the line](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/toe_the_line)" are idioms more appropriate when describing a person in a subordinate position, or trying to conform to other people's wishes and/or expectations.

"Get the better of" could be more appropriate if your goal is to describe, say, a high judge in a country with powerful and independent judiciary. He wants to be impartial out of considerations of honor etc., but sometimes emotions get the better of him. After all, he is a human being.

Another one:

> He fails to keep his emotions in check.

Another:

> He is driven by human passions and beset with human frailties.

Answer (score 0):

In English, we don't have a phrase for people being too emotional for their position. The closest I can think of is something like "they're very sad for being a clown," or something of that sort where the person's emotions do not seem to match what you would expect from their work.

However, for someone who gets angry easily you could say they are "hot tempered" or "hot headed." If they are just very emotional, you can call them "overemotional," but this is regarded as an insult.